# Are sewing-machines from elna and janome identical?

Tags: sewing-machine

It seems that Janome bought Elna some years ago.
Now, a lot of sewing-machines from Elna and Janome seem to be identical, but they differ in price.

For example *"Elna 864 air"* and *"Janome AirThread 2000D Professional"* seem to be the same, at leats it seems to be the same housing.
But *"Elna 864 air"* costs about 200€ more than *"Janome AirThread 2000D Professional"*.

I cannot see any difference.
Is there any difference that only experts can see?
Is there any difference in quality and/or lifetime?
For example, does one use plastic parts while the other uses steel parts?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for product comparison.

Comment: @Joachim I know that product comparisons are likely to be opinion-based question, but I am not asking for an opinion.
I just want to know if these machines differ in more than their brands.
I have modified my questions to make it more clear.

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts.  The push-back on your question isn't that it's opinion-based.  The site scope does include questions about the best kinds of tools for your project.  So, "I want to do ABC; do I need a sewing machine with feature XYZ to accomplish that?" would be an on-topic question.  But comparing the specifications of different sewing machine models  is essentially requesting help shopping for a sewing machine, which isn't within the site's scope.  You might be able to get an answer, though, by contacting the company's customer service department.

Comment: Maybe ask a store owner...

Comment: Or call or email the manufacturer or a sales person. Say you are interested in the machines and ask them about specific differences between what appear as identical models. I am sure they will explain why the high end models (more expensive) are better.

Comment: I think that this is on-topic, although it's a bit challenging, since you're basically asking about the features and/or longevity of the machines. [I'll add a side note... I used to work for a car manufacturer that owned a few brands in different countries; the car models all had different names (e.g. the Company1 Trip and the Company2 Journey) but contained identical components other than minor branding. The pricing was still slightly different because the assembly factories and other overhead influenced things differently. How brands end up being priced can be pretty obscure!]

Comment: I’m again voting to close this question because it is asking for product comparison. Product comparison is not necessarily opinion-based (and this question seems to look for technical differences [also not for features of a single model]). This is also no 'tool selection' question, which intended use is to find tool suitable for a specific job. There is no mention of a specific task the OP wants to perform for which any of the two machines mentioned might be better.

Comment: Strange, the question was pretty straight forward ...two servers from the same manufacturer..are they identical?